# Objective-C (iOS) : NSData to long long value?

Tags: objective-c, nsdata, long-integer

I'm sending a 8 bytes numeric value over the network (from a c# windows server) that needs to be received by my iDevice. The value is a "long" variable on my server (System.Int64). I checked that the value is correctly converted to a byte array using

```
byte[] valueBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(mylongvalue);
```

The data is received on the iDevice via a NSData variable. I need to skip the first 3 bytes, and then read the 8 next bytes to compute my long long value.

I tried this:

```
NSData * longlongValueBytes = [receivedData subDataWithRange:NSMakeRange(3,8)];
long long receivedLongLongValue = *(const long long *)[longlongValueBytes bytes];
```

But this only works for values below 128. Each sent values above or equal to 128 always returns 127 when received.

What am I missing ? Could this be related to a sign problem, or maybe an endianness problem?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: One thing you need to beware of is endianness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check (using the debugger or some `NSLog`) the raw content of your NSData to be sure it is received correctly?

*Especially check that you don't have different endianness between your different systems (your Windows Server and the iOS device). In general before sending bytes to the network, one try to make sure they are represented in the "network byte order" which corresponds to the "big-endian" order (Most Significant Byte first), regardless of the endianness of the sender or receiver.*

You can write `NSLog(@"data: %@", longlongValueBytes);` in your code to see the hexadecimal representation of your data and check that you received the expected bytes.

Then to convert those bytes into a `long long`, try this instead of your code:

```
unsigned long long receivedLongLongValue = 0;
[longlongValueBytes getBytes:&receivedLongLongValue length:8];
NSLog(@"received long value: %llu", receivedLongLongValue);
```

Comment: It seems that my data is sent using Little Endian (least significant byte first), but what is really strange is that once the value 7F000000 00000000 (127) is reached, the data isn't received anymore by the iDevice... But if I send my value as a string and convert it to an unsigned long on the iDevice, everything's fine... I really don't get it.

Comment: Start by converting your data to Big Endian (Network Byte Order) before sending it and check what you receive each time then.

Comment: Will do that. Thanks a lot for your help! :)

Comment: I figured out my problem, in fact it was my mistake. I tried to make a copy of all the data to an UTF8 string before handling it byte-by-byte, and since UTF8 doesn't allow characters above 127 the conversion failed, making the rest of my code buggy.

Comment: Ok thanks for the feedback ;) _(Don't forget to mark your question as solved)_